# Login.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at Login.js:22:1) at handleSubmit (Login.js:22:1) why i am getting error

Tags: xcode

My beckend api is working fine but when i am trying to connect it with front end it is throwing syntex error. why i amgetting this error.

[[[BeckEnd
[frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUfSv.png)| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
| Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXLKY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKNBZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45wt1.png)| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
| Cell 3   | Cell 4   |

```
Beckend API
router.post("/login", [
body('email', 'Enter a valid email').isEmail(),
body('password', 'Password can not be blank').exists()
],
async (req, res) => {
    //If there are errors, return bad request with errors.
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array(), 
   message: "Validation Error" });
    }

    //Check whether the user with this email exist or not
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        //Finding the user with existing email
        let user = await User.findOne({email});
        if (!user) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Please try to log in 
       with correct credential." })
        }
        //Comparing the password with the existing one
        const passwordCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, 
       user.password);
        if (!passwordCompare) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Please try to log in 
        with correct credential." })
        }

        //Log in the user after validation with the help of auth 
        token
        const data = {
            user: {
                id: user.id,
            }
        };

        const authtoken = jwt.sign(data, jwt_token_secret);

        //res.json(user);
        res.json({authtoken: authtoken});

    }

    //Catch errors
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).send("Server error");
    }
    });

    FrontEnd code
    const [credentials,setCredentials] = useState({email: 
     "",password: ""})

    const handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await 
    fetch("http://localhost:5001/api/auth/login",{
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({email: credentials.email, password: 
   credentials.password}),
    });

    const result = await response.json()
    console.log(result);
}

const onChange = (e) =>{
    setCredentials({...credentials, [e.target.name]: 
 e.target.value})
}
```

i am sharing my fontend and beckend code below
can't resolve this error. help me please

Comment: Please post code as text, not images of text.